# Xamarin NavigationBar back button click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am developing a xamarin forms application in which I need to intercept the navigation bar back button. I could do this in android by the 
OnOptionsItemSelected method in the activity.
How can I do this in iOS platform? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the XAML Page you can set the has back button to false:

```
<ContentPage 
    NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
    Title="MyPage">
</ContentPage>
```

And for Android device,you need to disable the physical back button function:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    //return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
      return true;
}
```